# Chainlink Request Event Emit - Unsure whether events are being emitted, requests seem to be sucessful

Tags: ethereum, chainlink

I am trying to learn how to use the [ChainlinkClient](https://blog.chain.link/apis-smart-contracts-and-how-to-connect-them/) and I am using their example as well as one for the API that I am trying to uses.

You can see them here on this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/lukebyrne/203076b34a130073276aa4bf0c019d35).

The two contracts in the Gist are deployed on Rinkenby here:

- [APIConsumner.sol](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x401594dee6342a00ab522c44ad7c08eaf8517b1f)
- [APIConsumner2.sol](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xb306e2a5cc3adf26798a9adf567b9c0876c3566b)

When I call the requestData() method on both contracts they seems to work, the transactions goes through and Link gets taken from the contracts, I am however unable to determine whether the actual data I am requesting from the external APIs gets returned, either by looking in the transaction event or trying to access the value that I am setting.

I am a bit bamboozled at this point, any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the flag. The node that was hosting this is deprecated, the article has been updated, and the docs have the latest example.

Please use:

```
oracle = 0xc57B33452b4F7BB189bB5AfaE9cc4aBa1f7a4FD8;
jobId = "d5270d1c311941d0b08bead21fea7747";
```